# Convergence of infinite series of log function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check the convergence of the infinite series $\sum\limits\frac1{(\log n)^{3/2}}$.

I have tried to use comparison test but got no success.

Comment: Hint:$$(\log{(n)})^{3/2}\lt n\qquad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? Where are you stuck? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Have you learned the Cauchy Condensation test? That makes the term you're summing over immediately much more manageable.

Comment: Thanks for replying . I used the comparison test to prove that 1/log n is divergent (with 1/n).  I wasn't able to get such divergent series to make a conclusion.

Comment: @ Peter Foreman Thank u for the hint.  can you also give a proof for this identity?

Comment: @VishalSharma, Generally it's true that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{-k} \log x = 0$, by substituting $x = e^t$. Letting $k = 2/3$, we get that eventually, $x^{-2/3} \log x < 1$, so $\log x < x^{2 / 3}$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, For $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\operatorname{log}n)^p}$

We use Cauchy Condensation test,

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty 2^n \frac{1}{(\operatorname{log}2^n)^p}=\frac{1}{(\operatorname{log}2)^p} \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{2^n}{n^p}
\end{eqnarray}

which diverges for all $p>0$. Since $2^nn^{-p}\to \infty$ for all $p>0$